# mssql and node, am i doing connection pools right?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I am currently creating some web apps using nodejs.
Currently I have different routes setup for my various web apps. I am wondering if I am using pooling correctly, or if parts of my code are redundant. Don't have any errors. Do I have to do "const pool = new.sqlConnectionPool" per route? Thanks!

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./public'))
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
    var config = {
      driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
      connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=SERVER;Database=SQL_Testing;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    };


    app.get('/PickQueue', function (req, res) {
   
    var now = new Date();
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
        return pool.request().query("query goes here")
        }).then(result => {
          let rows = result.recordset
          res.status(200).json(rows);
          console.log('Grabbing QUEUE info '+ now);
          sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {
          res.status(500).send({ message: `${err}`})
          sql.close();
        });
      
});


app.get('/PackingStation/dipline1/:packDateTotal', function (req, res) {
   
    var now = new Date();

    const packDateTotal = "'"+req.params.packDateTotal+"'"
    const queryString = "DECLARE @date AS Varchar(100) = "
    var finalquery = queryString.concat(packDateTotal)
    var finalquery = finalquery.concat("query here ")
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
        return pool.request().query(finalquery)
        }).then(result => {
          let rows = result.recordset
          res.status(200).json(rows);
          console.log('Grabbing Dip1 Count info '+ now);
          sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {
          res.status(500).send({ message: `${err}`})
          sql.close();
        });
      
});

app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to initialize the pool once and then reuse it every where else, not each time there's a request incoming

just move that pool initialization somewhere else

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Should I do `const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);` before my routes and call it using `pool.connect().then(() => { `?

Comment: i would move `connect()` to the bootstrap process of teh server. in bootstrap, you can initialize connection pool for database, redis or whatever you need to do before serving requests. pass the pool object to wherever you need it (your route controller).